# Regex for Ruby code extraction out of plain text?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract ruby code snippets out of plain text.

Using the gem https://github.com/Erol/yomu makes it possible to extract the text of a PDF document. Now I want to get just the well-formed ruby code out of, for instance, a ruby-programming-book.

Any idea how a regex for multi-line matches of ruby methods and classes could look like?
I tried many different expressions, but did not get the results, that I expected.

Comment: Ruby's syntax is not a regular language. You can match it with regular expressions. Besides, since Ruby is very permissive, even the title of your question on its own is valid Ruby code. Just from raw text, it will be effectively impossible to extract just the ruby code and ignore the prose in between.

Comment: As the code in a book is used to be well-formed it should be possible. But I think you will need to count the block opening keywords of ruby, to recognize when a class, or methods ends..everything is possible

Comment: I tried smth like:
`Yomu.new("book.pdf").text.scan(/\nclass \ [a-z]*\n.*\nend\n/m)`
For ruby-class extraction. The use of linebreaks helps here for matching the right parts of the plain text.

Comment: Please share a link to the `pdf` itself. I believe, that code has different formatting, e.g. in monospaced font, which might be way more helpful, that parsing text, that already lacks this info.

Comment: [book.pdf](https://github.com/RogerTongTong/ruby_learning/raw/master/Pragmatic.Programming.Ruby.1.9.and.2.0.4th.Edition.Jun.2013.pdf)

Comment: @mminski https://pragprog.com/titles/ruby4/source_code

Comment: I wanted to do a similar thing with my mysh gem. I quickly realized that the syntax of Ruby was just too permissive for this to work without some help. I wound up placing my Ruby code inside a {{  }} structure. Yes this is stealing an idea called handlebars (stole the name too ;-) from, I think, Ember.JS but I could be wrong on that. I learned of handlebars while at an Ember meetup group, and the idea stuck with me.

Comment: Anyway, if its code embedded in a book you desire, you may be able to bracket it by looking for a style change.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

- Go through the file line by line and try to parse each line as Ruby code
- If a line parses as Ruby start adding more lines to it until they don't parse as Ruby code anymore
- Voila, here is your first code snippet
- Maybe apply some filter to exclude trivial snippets like single words
- Repeat

This is the common best practice to extract source code from unstructured text like emails and what not. This has been used to scan millions of emails for research projects.

Use the `ripper` core library to parse Ruby code.

Comment: Thanks, @akuhn, I like this approach.